# Does this mail mean that I've been granted Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

[image: Outcome Successful]

I've examined some mails from decision making centers on the net, but mine is the only one that tells 'the outcome of your application has been successful and dispatched.' Does that mean visa approved or it's just another way of telling the decision has been made, go and collect your passport and see the result? I wonder if I can learn the outcome of visa from those mails lately. Because as far as I know, we cannot learn it till we get the passport.

---

Guys first of all thank you for your answers. Actually I didn't post the whole mail as I found it unnecessary. I'm pretty sure the mail is legitimate, and this is the whole version.

[Decision Making Centre Mail](https://i.postimg.cc/nhqS6xwY/Ekran-Al-nt-s.png)

I read something like i could upload all the files they need while applying visa since the beginning of this last April. With this novelty, i dont know if i should consider the ''outcome of your application has been successful'' is a new thing that from now on we can learn whether we have granted visa or not.

---

Guys I was going to write the result of my visa application, sorry for editing late. I got the visa, and I asked an officer working at VAC if there was any possibility that we could learn from the email writing 'the outcome of your application has been successful '. They said there never exists a single indication whether to get the visa from emails,so it's better not to think about the mails we get too much. Just think positive and wait for your passport to arrive. Thanks a lot for your all answers!!!

Comment: That's a nice one. It's the first time I have seen that message. It does seem to add fuel to the conspiracy theories about these notifications and this one, even to me, looks like its a Yes. Who Knows?

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Some of the below answers maybe correct but my answer below is with the limited info provided in the original question. That said, I'd still use the guidelines detailed below:

There are a few things that make it suspicious for me:

1. The use of "Customer" instead of your name
2. "The outcome..." instead of clearly saying "Your visa has been approved" or "You have been granted a visa" or something clear like that
3. There is a chance that if you open the survey link, they will ask you for some sensitive information. Be careful. Usually service providers send a separate link, often, days after the appointment and the result to seek your feedback. I have so far not seen surveys being sent in the same email.

I'd also advise you to look at the email and see if it looks legit. You could call the consulate or the agency that helped you with your visa interview/appointment to see if the email sender is the right one.

Comment: The survey seems non intrusive and looks legitimate.

Comment: Can't claim it is legitimate too. The contents of the survey are not known. Also, the OP hasn't shared info about the sender of the email. So as I pointed out, with the info we have, I am still not sure. It is also better to not build up false hope.

Comment: I opened the link and looked at the survey questions, they seem legit enough although I understand the point of view of your answer.

Comment: @RedBaron: That's if we assume that the link goes to the address spelled out in the link text. This is not necessarily true, especially not if the email is suspected of being dishonest in the first place.

Comment: All over the world you will find companies that look deceptively like the official agency and charge you more money to pass your application on to the official agency, with no benefit for you. You may have applied through such a company without knowing, which would explain the "Dear Customer".

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it means that you got UK visa. And I can now definitely say that based on my experience.

In previous month we had 6 applications and all of them had the following email from the Istanbul Visa Decision Center:

> Dear Customer
>
> **The outcome of your application has been successful and dispatched.** Please allow 1-3 days for your documents to arrive at your visa application centre or to be couriered back to you (if you have purchased this option). You can track your application on TLS website.
>
> At UK Visas and Immigration we continually strive to improve our customer service offer and would really appreciate your feedback on your experience via this short survey https://www.smartsurvey.co.uk/s/JYQ>SA/.Please be informed that your responses will remain anonymous.
>
> Regards
>
> UKVI Istanbul Decision Making Centre

We also had 2 applications which got visa refusal and email was a bit different:

> Dear Customer
>
> **The outcome of your application has been dispatched.** Please allow 1-3 
>   days for your documents to arrive at your visa application centre or to be couriered back to you (if you 
>   have purchased this option). You 
>   can track your application on TLS website.
>
> At UK Visas and Immigration we 
>   continually strive to improve our 
>   customer service offer and would really appreciate your feedback on your experience via this short survey https://www.smartsurvey.co.uk/s/JYQ>SA/ .Please be informed that your responses will remain anonymous.
>
> Regards
>
> UKVI Istanbul Decision Making Centre

So the difference is only in the word "successfull". If it there - you got your visa, if not - you get your passport with refusal letter. And it looks to be applicable to Istanbul center only.

When I did my web search - it appears that for Abu Dhabi center if the email says concluded than it means the visa was refused, if issued - than visa was granted.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: [Another answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137853/does-this-mail-mean-that-ive-been-granted-visa/138500#138500) seems more accurate and up-to-date than mine.**

It is hard to know until we find out a counter example (e.g. someone whose visa application was rejected), but I can share my experience of UKVI Istanbul.

I was granted three visas (two visitor visas, one work visa) between 2015 and 2018, they never disclosed the decision via e-mail. In 2015, phrasing of the e-mail was a little bit different as below.

> *ISTANvisainfo@fco.gov.uk*
>   
> *Tue 16-Jun-15*
>
> Dear Customer
>
> **A decision has now been made on your application.** Please allow 1-3
>   days for your documents to arrive at your visa application centre or
>   to be couriered back to you (if you have purchased this option).
>
> You can track your application on www.tpcontact.co.uk.
>
> Regards
>
> UKVI Istanbul Decision Making Centre

I don't think the word "successful" in your e-mail mean that the visa was granted. It should mean the process was completed. In any case, their phrasing is not clear.